# Trouble with SELECT statement - find Min, Max values under different conditions - SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, max

Here is how my selection looks like:

```
DocID   DocNumber   MilestoneDate   MilestoneID
30      14-1        2001-10-01  10
30      14-1        2001-10-15  11
30      14-1        2002-11-06  13
30      14-1        2003-11-01  27
30      14-1        2003-11-01  30
30      14-1        2004-03-01  28
30      14-1        2004-03-01  31
31      14-3        2003-06-27  13
31      14-3        2004-05-05  27
31      14-3        2004-05-05  30
31      14-3        2005-07-20  35
31      14-3        2005-08-31  23
36      1-2         1996-10-01  10
36      1-2         1996-10-01  11
36      1-2         1996-12-01  28
36      1-2         1996-12-01  31
```

I need to make a report out of this selection that would have 1 row per DocID.
It would have columns 
DocID, 
DocNumber, 
EarliestDate = if MilestoneID 10 or 11 not empty select greater out of these two else
               the earliest date out of other MilestoneIDs for that DocID (here is my trouble)
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should try and clean up your table (use 4 spaces at start to make it keep your format, and use spaces instead of tabs to delimited), as well as show a sample of what SELECT you have tried. It is easier to show a problem in your existing code than to create a brand new query often times.

Comment: Show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: here is what i tried:select 
DocID, DocNumber, 
CASE When (MAX(MilestoneID) = 10 or MAX(MilestoneID) = 11) and Not Max(MilestoneDate) is Null THEN Max(MilestoneDAte) END as Earliest
FROM table
 From

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (DocID INT, DocNumber VARCHAR(10), MilestoneDate DATETIME, MilestoneID INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (30, '14-1', '10-01-2001', 10)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (30, '14-1', '10-15-2001', 11)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (30, '14-1', '11-06-2002', 13)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (30, '14-1', '11-01-2003', 27)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (30, '14-1', '11-01-2003', 30)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (30, '14-1', '03-01-2004', 28)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (30, '14-1', '03-01-2004', 31)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (31, '14-3', '06-27-2003', 13)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (31, '14-3', '05-05-2004', 27)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (31, '14-3', '05-05-2004', 30)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (31, '14-3', '07-20-2005', 35)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (31, '14-3', '08-31-2005', 23)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (36, '1-2', '10-01-1996', 10)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (36, '1-2', '10-01-1996', 11)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (36, '1-2', '12-01-1996', 28)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (36, '1-2', '12-01-1996', 31)

-- get the items where we want the max
SELECT DocID, DocNumber, MAX(MilestoneDate) AS MilestoneDate
FROM @Table WHERE MilestoneID IN (10, 11)
GROUP BY DocID, DocNumber
UNION -- get the items where we want the min
SELECT DocID, DocNumber, MIN(MilestoneDate)
FROM @Table 
WHERE DocID NOT IN (SELECT DocID FROM @Table WHERE MilestoneID IN (10, 11))
GROUP BY DocID, DocNumber

Result:
DocID      DocNumber        MilestoneDate
30         14-1             2001-10-15 00:00:00.000
31         14-3             2003-06-27 00:00:00.000
36         1-2              1996-10-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This gives the result I want. Now I have trouble incorporating this logic into my more complex query. This is basicly result for one of the columns I need. I will add my whole query to give you an insight.

Comment: You can edit your original post to include the more detailed query.  If you edit my post, it will get rejected.

Comment: Thanks that is what I did, but didn't know that it would be rejected :)

Comment: If my post was helpful, it'd be great if you could mark it as the answer or up-vote it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t.DocID,
    t.DocNumber,
    EarliestDate = 
        ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN t.MilestoneID IN (10, 11)
                        THEN t.MilestoneDate END),
               MIN(CASE WHEN t.MilestoneID IN (10, 11)
                        THEN NULL ELSE t.MilestoneDate END))
FROM [table] t
GROUP BY
    t.DocID,
    t.DocNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

I came with a solution for my problem.

Any suggestions for improvement are more then welcome.
Since I needed to incorporate suggestion that pvanhouten gave me into another query I decided to do something like this:

```
Select t1.DocID, t1.DocNumber, t1.DocTitle, t1.DevStatus, t1.GrOrgType, t1.DocType,  
       t1.WebStatus, t1.RecommandType, t1.ProjectPlanApprovedBySponsor, 
       t1.ProjectPlanApprovedByWG, t1.Completed, t2.MilestoneDate as EarliestDate From
  (Select * From 
   (Select distinct d.DocID, d.DocNumber, d.DocTitle,dm.MilestoneDate,lkpds.DevStatus,   
                    lkpgt.GrOrgType, lkpdt.DocType, lkpws.WebStatus, lkprt.RecommandType,
        CASE dm.MilestoneId 
          WHEN 10 Then 'PPAW'
          WHEN 11 Then 'PPAS'
          WHEN 35 Then 'Completed'
        END as [MilestoneName],   

       (CASE WHEN not dv.DocID  is Null THEN 'Yes' END) OldVersionExist

        FROM Document d LEFT JOIN lkpDocDevStatus lkpds ON d.DocDevStatID = lkpds.DocDevStatID
            LEFT JOIN lkpDocType lkpdt ON d.DocTypeID = lkpdt.DocTypeID
            LEFT JOIN lkpDocRecType lkprt ON d.DocRecTypeID = lkprt.DocRecTypeID
            LEFT JOIN lkpWebStatus lkpws ON d.WebStatID = lkpws.WebStatID
            LEFT JOIN Doc_Group dg ON d.DocID = dg.DocID
            LEFT JOIN GroupOrg gro ON dg.GroupID = gro.GroupID
            LEFT JOIN lkpGroupOrgType lkpgt ON lkpgt.GrOrgTypeID = gro.GrOrgTypeID
            LEFT JOIN Doc_Milestone dm ON d.DocID = dm.DocID
            JOIN Milestones m ON m.MilestoneID = dm.MilestoneID
            LEFT JOIN Doc_Version dv ON d.DocID = dv.DocID

         Where dg.GrOrgRoleID = 5 and lkpds.DocDevStatID <> 1 and  lkpds.DocDevStatID <> 9             

 Group By d.DocID, d.DocNumber, d.DocTitle, lkpds.DevStatus, lkpds.DocDevStatID,  
          lkpgt.GrOrgType, lkpdt.DocType, 
          lkpws.WebStatus, lkprt.RecommandType, dv.docID, dm.MilestoneDate, dm.Milestoneid) T

 PIVOT
 (
  Max(MilestoneDate)
  FOR [MilestoneName] IN ([PPAW],[PPAS],[Completed])
  ) AS PivotTable
 ) t1

 JOIN 
  (SELECT dm.DocID , MAX(MilestoneDate) AS MilestoneDate 
     FROM document d JOIN Doc_Milestone as dm ON d.DocID = dm.DociD WHERE MilestoneID IN (10,   
      11) 
     GROUP BY dm.DocID
     UNION -- get the items where we want the min 
     SELECT dm.DocID, MIN(MilestoneDate) 
     FROM document d JOIN Doc_Milestone as dm ON d.DocID = dm.DociD  
     WHERE dm.DocID NOT IN (SELECT dm.DocID FROM Doc_Milestone as dm WHERE dm.MilestoneID IN (10,
     11)) 
     GROUP BY dm.DocID) as t2

 ON t1.DocID = t2.DocID
```